# Xamarin.Forms application Icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does someone know where or how I can set the Xamarin.Forms Application icon and or Launchscreen ?

Tried in visual studio properties of my current project but I don't see the option there.

Comment: Nice question, also needed this ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each platform should have its own project that you can access. You set these things in the properties of the these (if you are in Xamarin Studio). In Visual Studio I think you can edit the info.plist for iOS and the manifest for Android (both of these are located in the platform specific projects).

Comment: Also, since icons are resolution dependent, and like you said dependent on OS, there actually are like 50 or so icons.. I never really counted exactly. There are some tools (online tools too) that help create required formats from one high quality "master". http://makeappicon.com/ and many more (just google).

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the icon.png in the "drawable" folder(s) in the android project and the resources dir for iOS. There are different drawable folders in Android, etc.  For more info on Xamarin forms and images check out this link:

[Working with Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer